# DataTable: move row to new column based on duplicate ID

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I would like to move all duplicate rows to a new column, based on ID. 
This is my actual DataTable.

```
+----+-------+--------------------------+
| ID | Name  |          Shift           |
+----+-------+--------------------------+
|  1 | Mike  | 01.01.2020 - 15:00/17:00 |
|  2 | Jerry | 02.02.2020 - 10:00/12:00 |
|  3 | Luis  | 03.03.2020 - 09:00/11:00 |
|  1 | Mike  | 03.03.2020 - 09:00/11:00 |
+----+-------+--------------------------+
```

And this is the result I'd like to get:

```
+----+-------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| ID | Name  |         Shift01          |         Shift02          |
+----+-------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|  1 | Mike  | 01.01.2020 - 15:00/17:00 | 03.03.2020 - 09:00/11:00 |
|  2 | Jerry | 02.02.2020 - 10:00/12:00 |                          |
|  3 | Luis  | 03.03.2020 - 09:00/11:00 |                          |
+----+-------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Have you considered adding another column with the shift number instead? That way you would only ever need that one extra column, instead of more columns as more shifts arose.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your comment. I understand that my table is not best practice and full of redundant data, but I need to keep it that way in order to create a mail merge in Excel after.

Comment: What if Mike has more rows? Add Shift#` column for each?

Comment: The goal is to dinamically add new columns based on the number of shifts that one person has

Comment: @krusty What you could do is write down the steps to achieve the result. For example, you might start by finding the ID with the maximum number of occurences and adding that many columns to the table, to get that part over and done with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the original DataTable as follows:

```vb
Dim orgDT As New DataTable
orgDT.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
orgDT.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
orgDT.Columns.Add("Shift", GetType(String))
```

Filled with

```vb
orgDT.Rows.Add(1, "Mike", "01.01.2020 - 15:00 / 17:00")
orgDT.Rows.Add(2, "Jerry", "02.02.2020 - 10:00 / 12:00")
orgDT.Rows.Add(3, "Luis", "03.03.2020 - 09:00 / 11:00")
orgDT.Rows.Add(1, "Mike", "03.03.2020 - 09:00 / 11:00")
orgDT.Rows.Add(3, "Luis", "03.03.2020 - 04:00 / 08:00")
orgDT.Rows.Add(1, "Mike", "03.04.2020 - 07:00 / 10:00")
```

To produce the second DataTable:

- group the original DataTable by the `ID` column.
- Get the max grouping count which is the number of the shifts.
- Collect the values from the groups to add new rows.

```vb
Dim resDT As New DataTable
resDT.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
resDT.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))

Dim groups = orgDT.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(r) r.Field(Of Integer)("ID"))
Dim shiftCount = groups.Max(Function(g) g.Count)
Dim row As New List(Of String)

For i = 1 To shiftCount
    resDT.Columns.Add($"Shift{i.ToString("00")}", GetType(String))
Next

For Each group In groups
    row.Clear()
    row.Add(group.Key.ToString)
    row.Add(group.First.Field(Of String)("Name"))
    row.AddRange(group.Select(Function(g) g.Field(Of String)("Shift")))

    resDT.Rows.Add(row.ToArray)
Next
```

This is the outcome...

[image: SOA62672973]